# How to make ldappasswd use {SHA} instead of {SSHA} for users passwords in openldap?

Tags: passwords, openldap, sha

Is it possible to use {SHA} with ldappasswd? I didn't find responsible option in manual page and docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `password-hash` in `slapd.conf(5)`, or for `olcPasswordHash` in `slapd-config(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old post but I found another solution for this problem.

This wolution works for **ApacheDirectory servers** (for org.apache implementation classes, but I think you can find interceptors for each openldap).

If you want use **SHA** encrypting by default when using `ldappasswd` you can change the interceptor implementation of password.

You have to modify following dn entry:

```
ads-interceptorId=passwordHashingInterceptor,ou=interceptors,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
```

And change the value:
`ads-interceptorclassname: arg.apache.directory.server.core.hash.ShaPasswordHashingInterceptor`

By default, openldap is using:

```
ads-interceptorclassname: org.apache.directory.server.core.hash.SshaPasswordHashingInterceptor
```

Command to modify:

```
ldapmodify -h <LDAP_HOST> -p <LDAP_PORT> -D "<ADMIN_DN>" -w "<ADMIN_PASSWORD>" <<EOF
dn: ads-interceptorId=passwordHashingInterceptor,ou=interceptors,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
changetype: modify
replace: ads-interceptorclassname
ads-interceptorclassname: org.apache.directory.server.core.hash.ShaPasswordHashingInterceptor
EOF
```

Then you have to restart your LDAP server. All new passwords added by `ldappasswd` will be in **SHA** and not in **SSHA**.

**Note:**
You can use another interceptor provided by Apache:
http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/1.4-interceptors.html#existing-interceptors
Javadoc:
https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/gen-docs/2.0.0-M20/apidocs/org/apache/directory/server/core/hash/package-tree.html